# What's the difference between $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

since no one asked yet because it might be a dumb question but I frequently encounter these two notations along in the same proof are they different from each other or do they both refer to the space of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries?

Comment: $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$, $\mathbb R^{n,n},$ $(\textrm{any variant of M})_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$ and $(\textrm{any variant of M})_n(\mathbb R)$ are different ways for writting the same set.

Comment: Can you give an example where the notations appear in the same proof? That does seem a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notation varies a lot in math, and the exact meaning of what something means depends on the context.

$A\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ means that $A$ is an element of the ring of $n \times n$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ pretty clearly indicates that $A$ is an element of an $n \times n$ tuple with real coefficients.

These are not the same thing. With $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ we know that $A$ is an element of a ring and so if we are given a $B\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ we know how to compute $A+B$ and $AB$.

I feel like this is not is clear for $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Like, if we are given $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, then perhaps you could compute $A+B$ and $AB$ by adding and multiplying the corresponding tuple entries. In this case, multiplying elements of $\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is very different than multiplying elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

However, under the natural definitions of scalar multiplication and vector addiction, $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ becomes an $n \times n$ dimensional vector space with real coefficients. Since $\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is also an $n \times n$ vector space with real coefficients, in this case we have that $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic as vector spaces.

Sorry if this was a bit rambly, hope it helped.

Comment: That was my thought too: $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is simply $\Bbb R^{n^2}$. But Theo Bendit's answer says no: $n\times n$ signifies that it probably means the ring of $n\times n$ matrices. So it's not that clear cut.

Comment: @TonyK I don't have a reference on hand, but I have definitely seen $\Bbb{R}^{n \times n}$ refer to the set of $n \times n$ real matrices multiple times.

Comment: @azif00: you are forgetting the multiplication operation. This is defined in a ring of matrices, but not in $\Bbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: Edit: A **$n \times n$ matrix with coefficients in $A$** (for some set $A$) is a function $n \times n \to A$, where we should view $n$ as the set $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, and $\times$ denotes the cartesian product. Also, an **$I$-tuple with entries in $A$** ($I$ an *index* set, i.e. just a set) is a function $I \to A$. So $$A^{n \times n} = \{\textrm{functions } n \times n \to A\} = \mathcal M_{n \times n}(A)$$ *as sets* (forgetting for now the additional structures that we can put on it).

Comment: I love "vector addiction"! Please, everybody, don't fix it. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Yes, @azif00. But we are talking about $\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, which is is not just "A $n\times n$ matrix" $-$ it contains the multiplication operation as part of its definition.

Answer (score 3):

I've only ever seen these notations refer to the same set. The latter is slightly less compact than the former, but the former could conceivably be misinterpreted as $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$. Without any further context, I'd say they mean the same thing.